# How to call a function after setting state is complete in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, use-effect

I would like to run `customFunction` only when `customEffect` has finished setting `isReady` state. And `customFunction` should only run once no matter if the `isReady` was set to `false` or `true` as long as it was ran after it was set.

```
import customFunction from 'myFile';

export const smallComponent = () => {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const customEffect = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await get(
          `some-api.com`,
        );
        return setIsReady(response); // response can be true or false
      } catch {
        return null;
      }
    };

    customEffect();

    customFunction();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>Hello World</>
  )

}
```

I tried to add isReady as second useEffect argument, but then my customFunction is being run before the customEffect finishes and then again after the isReady is being set.

Also tried having in a separate useEffect, but still seems to run before the customEffect finishes.

Comment: Does `customFunction` have any dependencies on the updated `isReady` value when it's set in `customEffect`?

Comment: In my case yes. I am using the value of isReady inside `customFunction`. But looks like your and p1uton solutions seem to do the job :)

Comment: Right, I figured it wasn't as simple as pushing `customFunction` call into the `customEffect` call. I updated my solution below again with a guard *after* `customFunction` is called to keep it from being called again later if the component ever rerenders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set initial value to `null` and use separate `useEffect` as Kevin suggested (only without checking `isReady` true/false).

In this case `setIsReady` will change `isReady` from null to true/false and the second `useEffect` will be called.

```
import customFunction from 'myFile';

export const smallComponent = () => {
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const customEffect = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await get(
                    `some-api.com`,
                );
                return setIsReady(response);
            } catch {
                return null;
            }
        };

        customEffect();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
       if (null === isReady) {
          return;
       }
       customFunction();
    }, [isReady]);

    return (
        <>Hello World</>
    )
}
```

Comment: I like this since it is only the single state, but the second effect still runs when the component mounts. Add an additional null check on `isReady` to only invoke `customFunction` when it's non-null.

Comment: yup, I tried and was surprised it was called twice. Null check might do it

Comment: Yes, forgot about this

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to cue an effect to run *after* the `isReady` state is set, and the value of `isReady` is irrelevant you can to use a second state value to indicate the first effect and state update has completed.

This will trigger the second effect to invoke `customFunction` but you don't want your component to remain in this state as from here any time the component rerenders the conditions will still be met. You'll want a third "state" to indicate the second effect has been triggered. Here you can use a React ref to indicate this.

```
export const smallComponent = () => {
  const [readySet, setReadySet] = useState(false);
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
  const customFunctionRunRef = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const customEffect = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await get(
          `some-api.com`,
        );

        setReadySet(true); // to trigger second effect callback
        return setIsReady(response); // response can be true or false
      } catch {
        return null;
      }
    };

    customEffect();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (readySet && !customFunctionRunRef.current) {
      // won't run before readySet is true
      // won't run after customFunctionRunRef true
      customFunction();
      customFunctionRunRef.current = true;
    }
  }, [readySet]);

  return (
    <>Hello World</>
  );
}
```

Better solution borrowed from @p1uton. Use null `isReady` state to indicate `customFunction` shouldn't invoke yet, and the ref to keep it from being invoked after.

```
export const smallComponent = () => {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(null);
  const customFunctionRunRef = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const customEffect = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await get(
          `some-api.com`,
        );

        return setIsReady(response); // response can be true or false
      } catch {
        return null;
      }
    };

    customEffect();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isReady !== null && !customFunctionRunRef.current) {
      // won't run before isReady is non-null
      // won't run after customFunctionRunRef true
      customFunction();
      customFunctionRunRef.current = true;
    }
  }, [isReady]);

  return (
    <>Hello World</>
  );
}
```

Comment: yea, had something similar in mind, but not feeling like it. I guess you code should also call `setReadySet` after `setIsReady` is being called.

But I think this is the cleanest way forward

Comment: @OFFLlNE Oops, lost an edit in there, meant to set the `readySet` state at the same time as `isReady` is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but this is how I would use a separate `useEffect`.

```
import customFunction from 'myFile';

export const smallComponent = () => {
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const customEffect = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await get(
                    `some-api.com`,
                );
                return setIsReady(response);
            } catch {
                return null;
            }
        };

        customEffect();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isReady) {
            return;
        }

        customFunction();
    }, [isReady]);

    return (
        <>Hello World</>
    )
}
```

Comment: Fair point. I will try to add more context :). The API can have the response as true or false. I would want it to be still ran if the API did `setIsReady(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this package, [isMounted](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ismounted)?

I used that in my projects.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import useIsMounted from 'ismounted';
import myService from './myService';
import Loading from './Loading';
import ResultsView from './ResultsView';
 
const MySecureComponent = () => {
  const isMounted = useIsMounted();
  const [results, setResults] = useState(null);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    myService.getResults().then(val => {
      if (isMounted.current) {
        setResults(val);
      }
    });
  }, [myService.getResults]);
 
  return results ? <ResultsView results={results} /> : <Loading />;
};
 
export default MySecureComponent;
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ismounted

Comment: I would want to believe this is possible without an external package. But thanks and I will take a look at that :)